# Selenium - Find link text containing random string

Tags: java, regex, selenium

I have to verify that this link exists on a page, and the link contains a random string of numbers between a file name and a date, similar to this:

Report-7895198-01282016.zip

I'm assuming I can use something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Report-" + somesortofregex + "-01282016.zip"))
```

How would I go about accomplishing this using linkText, or is there a better option?

Comment: please provide HTML code

Comment: `linkText` will search the page for the text of a hyper link, not the address that link leads to. You should try to use xpath instead. If you post the HTML code though I can write how you could do it.

Comment: The text is exactly the same as the name of the file. Here's the HTML:

`<a href="/adhoc/workspace/workspaceList.do?id=877875&amp;method=Download">Report-7895198-012816.zip</a>`

Answer (score 0):

you can use xpath here.. some thing like below

```
 //a[contains(text(),'Report-')][contains(text(),'-01282016.zip')]
```

please provide HTML code of the element to provide possible locators in this case.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Hey, that actually did exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)